# S3 Presigned URL Upload - The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method

Tags: java, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

node dependecy:

```
"aws-sdk": "^2.873.0",
```

I can get proper pre-signed url with js sdk;

```
  let params = {
    Bucket: s3_credentials.s3Bucket,
    Key: s3key,
    ContentType: contentType,
    ServerSideEncryption: 'aws:kms',
    SSEKMSKeyId: s3_credentials.kmsKeyName,
    Expires: 500 //time to expire in seconds
  };

  const signedUrl = s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params);
```

And response has **Content-Type, x-amz-server-side-encryption, x-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id**

maven dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-sdk-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.66</version>
    </dependency>
```

But when I use following java code there is no kms related params at presigned url response:

```
PutObjectRequest objectRequest = PutObjectRequest.builder()
    .bucket(SPEC_BUCKET_NAME)
    .key(s3Key)
    .contentType(contentType)
    .serverSideEncryption(ServerSideEncryption.AWS_KMS)
    .ssekmsKeyId(getKmsId())
    .expires(expiration)
    .build();

PutObjectPresignRequest presignRequest = PutObjectPresignRequest.builder().putObjectRequest(objectRequest).signatureDuration(Duration.ofMinutes(60)).build();

PresignedPutObjectRequest presignedRequestResponse = s3Presigner.presignPutObject(presignRequest);

String presignedUrl = presignedRequestResponse.url().toString();
```

This is kms id retrieve code:

```
  private String getKmsId() {
    KmsClient kmsClient = KmsClient.builder().build();
    DescribeKeyRequest req = DescribeKeyRequest.builder().keyId("alias/xxx").build();
    DescribeKeyResponse res = kmsClient.describeKey(req);

    logger.info(res.keyMetadata().toString());
    return res.keyMetadata().keyId();
  }
```

I also tried following

```
    .serverSideEncryption(ServerSideEncryption.AWS_KMS)
    .ssekmsKeyId("alias/xxxx")
```

Comment: How are you configuring the credentials for the Java application? This is a credentials issue most of the time

Comment: They are already running same vpc and also subnets. These are 2 services running at ecs. There is no special config for auth. I can already download files from s3 within java app